# Implementing BOSH and Ejabberd in Java Web application for chat and notifications

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejabberd

Is anyone implemented BOSH and Ejabberd in a java web application for chat and other purposes like notifications.

Is there any other way around..?

I want server to client push when anything new comes on server.

Answer (score 0):

There is many alternative available for push on web page.
ejabberd + XMPP + Bosh is just one of them. At ProcessOne we even build a Push Platform for that and there is a few other competitors.
Choosing the right platform highly depends on what you would like to achieve.

People will be able to make more relevant comments if you can share some details.

Comment: My main puprose is a chat module to implemnt and some notifications like user logged in..User added feedback..etc. ..like this.

Comment: So, you have a large number of possible alternative to implement this. XMPP is one of them. We try to make it simple with ProcessOne Push Platform, but there is other approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely easy to add things like push notifications when you already have a chat system that you are using for user to user messaging in your application.  I have customers that I have helped with this particular use case.

If you want chat and push notifications I'm sure you can find solutions that don't involve an XMPP server, but I'm not sure I would recommend them.  The XMPP protocol provides a lot of built in support for exchanging information with clients as well as routing information once your client has received it.  For example, you can send messages with special tags or xml namespaces so that your client can differentiate push notifications from normal user to user chat messages.  The [strophejs](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) library makes this particularly easy.

There is an [HTTP XMPP Gateway](http://chatmongers.com/blog/introducing-the-chatmongershttp-to-xmpp-gateway/) service that is available for allowing an application to send messages to XMPP users by way of an HTTP post.  It is definitely helpful for implementing push notifications in an application.